Vax Blade 4 BMS board issue (5 x 21700 cells Li-ion 18v battery)
I have a problem with our VAX blade 4 4.0ah battery.  Referencing this page: Repairing a 5-cell Li-ion battery: dead 21700 cells replaced, but BMS still reporting error when charging it seems that a number of other people have suffered with an issue with the board more than the batteries (ie lights one and three light up when you press the test button and won't charge).  In my case I've checked out the batteries - all very similar voltage, half charged, and resistance very similar but you can clearly see a defective / blown component on the board which has oozed out its stuff and dribbled down the board (hope that description is accepted on this technical forum!) (see pics).
Therefore  I believe the board alone would need replacing whilst the batteries are in a fit state.  You could question the root cause (why did the board blow in the first place) but my hunch is a defective component and not a result of a defective battery causing a spike or something.
This is all surface mount stuff so I'm not going to be able to replace this component and so does anyone know if you can get replacement boards?  All my searches so far keep finding 'compatible' units or ones on ebay saying for parts only (most likely defective board!).  I've searched for the P/N 280796 but no luck.
====Update 6/4/24: To clarify the help I'm looking for:

If the batteries are fine (which I believe they are), what steps can I do to diagnose the board further?
Will this lead help to plug into the diagnosis port (taking into consideration the voltage): https://uk.farnell.com/ftdi/ttl-232r-rpi/cable-debug-ttl-232-usb-rpi/dp/2147356
Please can I get some pointers in how to use a terminal to pull out the diagnosis report like in the post I referred to.  eg. What terminal commands would you call and if anyone has some knowledge of what to expect that would be great.
Other than AliExpress, is there a UK source for a replacement / aftermarket board?  I believe the board has a serial comms link to the hoover and if that isn't there the hoover won't work.





a defective / blown component on the board which has oozed out its stuff

Gosh no. There is no "stuff" inside those electronic components to ooze out. That's just flux from the soldering process at the factory that wasn't cleaned properly. That's not what caused the failure in your product.
Troubleshooting by eyeball can only get you so far and is often a "red herring". A proper and logical troubleshooting process is required.

Hi @DavideAndrew, thanks for the reply.  I'll certainly get a little brush and see what lies beneath.  In the meantime, could you give me some guidance in first steps to troubleshoot?  I would be keen to use the diagnostics port but don't have the right kit.  I only have the means to do RS232 stuff.

But that said, a quick search looks like for a few pounds I can get a usb to UART lead (designed for a Raspberry Pi but it says it will do 3.3v so that sounds like that's what I need: https://thepihut.com/products/usb-to-ttl-serial-cable-debug-console-cable-for-raspberry-pi?variant=27740547281
or
https://uk.farnell.com/ftdi/ttl-232r-rpi/cable-debug-ttl-232-usb-rpi/dp/2147356

OK. But, did I answer your question?

Hi @DavidAndrea, thanks for the guidance so far, I am looking for a bit more guidance on diagnosis and knowledge of a replacement board to be honest.  Your answer although greatly appreciated wasn't what I was expecting as it doesn't really look like flux that I'm familiar with but to be honest I can't rule it out (it's very powdery to the touch [under a magnifying glass]!) can you get powdery flux?  I've amended my question to request support on diagnosis.  I've got as far as finding a cable which i think (?) will help.
